# How do I decode this JSON string containing Magento product options?

Tags: javascript, json, magento

Magento stores product options in an encoded string as shown below. I am trying to figure out how to turn it into a usable object. I have tried eval('(' + below + ')') without success. It throws an undefined error:

> undefined:1
>   nY3VzdG9tcHJpbnR
>   ^

this is the sting I'm trying to parse:

```
 a:2:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:6:{s:4:"uenc";s:80:"aHR0cDovL2NnY3VzdG9tcHJpbnRpbmcuY29tLzE2eDI0LXByZW1pdW0tZ2FsbGVyeS13cmFwLmh0bWw,";s:7:"product";s:2:"12";s:15:"related_product";s:0:"";s:7:"options";a:2:{i:19;s:2:"16";i:18;a:9:{s:4:"type";s:24:"application/octet-stream";s:5:"title";s:16:"16x24 canvas.jpg";s:10:"quote_path";s:64:"/media/custom_options/quote/57cb4f796670cb680511f6fca1055a9f.jpg";s:10:"order_path";s:64:"/media/custom_options/order/57cb4f796670cb680511f6fca1055a9f.jpg";s:8:"fullpath";s:128:"/mnt/stor13-wc2-dfw1/480123/www.internetswebsite.com/web/content/media/custom_options/quote/57cb4f796670cb680511f6fca1055a9f.jpg";s:4:"size";s:7:"4692319";s:5:"width";i:4050;s:6:"height";i:2850;s:10:"secret_key";s:20:"ee79b5a12bfe9fc6c350";}}s:15:"options_18_file";s:83:"http://internetswebsite.com/media/tmp/uploader/57cb4f796670cb680511f6fca1055a9f.jpg";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";}s:7:"options";a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:5:"label";s:11:"Orientation";s:5:"value";s:22:"Landscape (Horizontal)";s:11:"print_value";s:22:"Landscape (Horizontal)";s:9:"option_id";s:2:"19";s:11:"option_type";s:5:"radio";s:12:"option_value";s:2:"16";s:11:"custom_view";b:0;}i:1;a:7:{s:5:"label";s:17:"Upload your photo";s:5:"value";s:162:"<a href="https://internetswebsite.com/sales/download/downloadCustomOption/id/35461/key/ee79b5a12bfe9fc6c350/" target="_blank">16x24 canvas.jpg</a> 4050 x 2850 px.";s:11:"print_value";s:32:"16x24 canvas.jpg 4050 x 2850 px.";s:9:"option_id";s:2:"18";s:11:"option_type";s:4:"file";s:12:"option_value";s:677:"a:10:{s:4:"type";s:24:"application/octet-stream";s:5:"title";s:16:"16x24 canvas.jpg";s:10:"quote_path";s:64:"/media/custom_options/quote/57cb4f796670cb680511f6fca1055a9f.jpg";s:10:"order_path";s:64:"/media/custom_options/order/57cb4f796670cb680511f6fca1055a9f.jpg";s:8:"fullpath";s:128:"/mnt/stor13-wc2-dfw1/480123/www.internetswebsite.com/web/content/media/custom_options/quote/57cb4f796670cb680511f6fca1055a9f.jpg";s:4:"size";s:7:"4692319";s:5:"width";i:4050;s:6:"height";i:2850;s:10:"secret_key";s:20:"ee79b5a12bfe9fc6c350";s:3:"url";a:2:{s:5:"route";s:35:"sales/download/downloadCustomOption";s:6:"params";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:5:"35461";s:3:"key";s:20:"ee79b5a12bfe9fc6c350";}}}";s:11:"custom_view";b:1;}}}
```

Any idea how to go about this in javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you should use php :-) (unserialize)

Comment: The following string is not Json but php serialize data. You cannot easily parse it in Javascript (I guess some lib exist but doesn't make sense). You should first unserialize it in PHP and then encode it Json before to send it.

Comment: I am accessing this from the api, not from within magento. Too bad that the api provides this data in this way if I'm forced to use php to consume the data.

Comment: Which part of the API send you this data? Can you give more details? because that sounds strange (ok magento sometime is strange :-)

Comment: In the worse case get a look to the following url: http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize:571

Comment: It is from sales_order.info. I will take a look at the phpjs unserialize. Thanks.